# This page isn’t working 90.0.0.11 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php

When I remove this code, the page opens or else it shows the error. Error and code is the following:

**Error**

This page isn’t working

90.0.0.11 is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500

```
if(isset($getRegisterDtl))
        {       
            $success=0;
            $fname=$_POST['fName'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $password=$_POST['password'];
            $md5=md5($password)
            $insertSql="insert into admin_users (name,user_name,password,mobile) values ('$fname','$email','$password', '$phone')";
            if(mysqli_query($conn,$insertSql))
            {
                $success=1;
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            }
            else
            {
                $success=2;
            }

        }
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: use : ini_set('display_errors', TRUE); on the top of you page to display the errors

Comment: In addition to the missing semicolon after your MD5 line... you shouldn't be using `md5()` at **all**. It's a horribly weak algorithm, and is essentially the same as storing your passwords in plaintext.  In addition to this, you should use use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL injection, which you're currently vulnerable to.

Comment: thanks for the valuable  suggestions Obsidian Age and Penguine. I will take look at it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no semicolon after `$md5=md5($password)`. Use this code.

```
if(isset($getRegisterDtl)){       
    $success=0;
    $fname=$_POST['fName'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $md5=md5($password);
    $insertSql="insert into admin_users (name,user_name,password,mobile) values ('$fname','$email','$password', '$phone')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$insertSql))
    {
        $success=1;
        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    }
    else
    {
        $success=2;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is useful. is there anyouter way to debug php code?

Comment: @LogeshS Many ways. What did you try? Any reporting function should have told you the line number. Example https://3v4l.org/GrQVE

Comment: I don't know how to debug the code in php. I asking for the help to debug the code like done in C. @user3783243.

Comment: @LogeshS There are different ways to debug your PHP code. The most common and important one is to enable `display_errors` and set the error reporting level maximum, `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` or defining the custom error handling function. The latter I recommend.